# Adding content between a PHP shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a shortcode in a theme that displays only when a user is logged out. Usually, I would use the following shortcode to achieve this

```
[logged_out]Content[/logged_out]
```

How would I achieve this in PHP?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[logged_out]"); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just try the code like below,

```
<?php
$string = 'Hello world';
echo do_shortcode('[logged_out]'.$string.'[/logged_out]');
?>
```

you can assign any value to the variable $string ;

Or you can directly use like this,

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode('[logged_out]Hello world[/logged_out]');
?>
```

For more information please refer,

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Answer (score 0):

you can use following way in your php file.

```
echo do_shortcode('[logged_out] your content [/logged_out]');
```